# How to install ssl in magento 2 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: magento2

I need help with installing SSL in my VPS.
I am stuck in apache2 Magento configurations.
I have changed all the options from Magento 2 backend and now the site is not working 
Kindly help with apache config and how can I redirect the site to https 
This is what I am using

```
< IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName spalding.co.in
        ServerAlias    www.spalding.co.in
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/spalding
        <Directory /var/www/html/spaldng/>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/5195fdcb4d95bdda.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/spalding.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

and I am confused about editing default-ssl.conf file do I need to edit this?

Comment: restart apache2 service and check it.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your certificate path with this.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/5195fdcb4d95bdda.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/spalding.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
```

And move the file to `certs` and `private` folder.

Restart apache and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me in 000-default.conf file in apache2

`<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin admin@spalding.co.in
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/spalding
         ServerName spalding.co.in
          ServerAlias www.spalding.co.in
         SSLEngine on
          SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/f942dd2fd74f5884.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/spalding.co.in.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
<Directory /var/www/html/spalding>
     Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName spalding.co.in
      ServerAlias www.spalding.co.in
      Redirect permanent / https://www.spalding.co.in
</VirtualHost>`